# ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'scikit_keras'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

i cant figure aou where im doing wrong,`

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score, mean_absolute_error, median_absolute_error
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import  SimpleImputer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit, StratifiedKFold, KFold, train_test_split, cross_val_score, GridSearchCV, ShuffleSplit
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from scikit_keras import KerasClassifier
```

i installed all the packages using pip command and also as suggested in other post i used
`pip install patchify`
but still get error
`xception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'scikit_keras'`
next i give a list of all package version
`Name: scikit-learn Version: 1.2.0 Name: pandas Version: 1.5.2 Name: yfinance Version: 0.1.90 Name: numpy Version: 1.23.5 Name: tensorflow Version: 2.11.0 Name: keras Version: 2.11.0`

Comment: Just a heads-up: there are like a dozen 3rd party libraries that are neither `scikit-learn` nor `TensorFlow` / `keras` that implement something like this (see also: https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras, https://github.com/daviddiazvico/scikit-keras). Keras and scikit-learn are well-maintained and you're *usually* better off sticking with the API they implement.

Comment: Try using a conda environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you installed [`scikit-keras`](https://github.com/daviddiazvico/scikit-keras) which implements a [`KerasClassifier`](https://github.com/daviddiazvico/scikit-keras/blob/f77508a4202e1098f5d68b82066cd6fa17035309/skkeras/scikit_learn.py#L257).

Which means the last line should be:

```
from skkeras import KerasClassifier
```